# a question in soft topology

Tags: general-topology, fuzzy-logic

The definition of soft topology is: 
[image]

**My question is**, isn't the soft topology in the folowing example lack the intersection and the union of two of it's sets? [image]

I mean, shouldn't the sets $\{\{\phi\},\{x,y,z\}\}$ and {{x,y},{x,y,z}} also be there?

**here is the definition of a soft set:**
[image]

Comment: What is a soft set?

Comment: I added above the definition, in my original question

Comment: Seems to be. Is the definition of intersection and union what we expect it to be?

Comment: Yes, intersections and unions are intersections amd unions of images of every parameter.
I have looked at some other examples of that article. my conclusion was that $\tau$ in that example was not meant to be a topology. just some basic set of sets that will help to demonstrait neighborhoods.
Thank You!